# Find the symmetric matrix that represents the quadratic form $Q(X)=trace(X^2)$, $X\in mat_n\mathbb (R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, quadratic-forms

as the title says, find the symmetric matrix (or signature) of $Q(X)=trace(X^2)$ where $X$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix with real entries.

the diagonal of $X^2$ is $$\sum_{k=1}^n x_{ik}x_{ki}$$

So $$Q(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n x_{ik}x_{ki}$$

How does this help us find the signature?

Comment: You have to pick a basis you're going to use to write $Q$. Let's use the standard basis, consisting of the matrices $E_{ij}$ which are all 0 except for a $1$ in the $ij$ position. Order them as $E_{11}, E_{12}, \ldots, E_{1n}, E_{21}, \ldots, E_{nn}$. So your matrix $Q$ will be $n^2 \times n^2$. The $(s,t)$ entry of $Q$ tells you how often $v_s v_t$ appears in the formula for $v^t Q v$, where $v$ is the coordinate vector for your matrix (which is basically its entries, read in order). Actually, the $(s,t)$ plus the $(t,s)$ entry tells you that. How often does $x_{12}x_{12}$ appear in Q(X)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple to show that the quadratic form
$$\Phi(X)=\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)$$
is definite positive.

Now if $X$ is symmetric then $Q(X)=\Phi(X)$ then $Q$ is definite positive on the space of symmetric matrices and if $X$ is antisymmetric then $Q(X)=-\Phi(X)$ hence $Q$ is definite negative on the space of antisymmetric matrices and we have
$$\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb R)=\mathcal S_n(\Bbb R)\oplus \mathcal{AS}(\Bbb R)$$
Can you deduce the signature of $Q$?

Comment: I don't think its definite positive. consider $X=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. In that case, $X^2=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ and $trace(X^2)=-2$

Comment: Surely $Q$ isn't definite positive where you see I said that?

Comment: Aaahhh now I see what you did...

Comment: Can you deduce then the signature?

Comment: The signature of Q is $(\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\frac{n(1-n)}{2},0)$?

Comment: Right if you consider the signature is $(n_+,n_-,n_0)$.

Comment: @Oria: your $n_{-}$ looks wrong; should be $n(n-1)/2$, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate on my comment above by looking at the case of $2 \times 2$ matrices. The coordinates of the matrix $M = \begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{bmatrix}$ in the standard basis are the vector
$$
v = \begin{bmatrix}
a\\c\\b\\d
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

(If we reordered the basis, the order would look better.)

What's $Q(M)$? It's
$$
Q(M) = aa + cb + bc + dd
$$
Now is $A$ is the matrix for the quadratic form $Q$, then $a_{11}$ tells you how many times $a^2$ appears in this formula, and $a_{12}$ tells you how many times $ac$ appears, and $a_{21}$ tells you how many times $ca$ appears, and so on. Of course, the matrix is symmetric, and $ac = ca$, so in an expression like the one above, where we have both $cb$ and $bc$, you attribute the $cb$ to entry $23$ and the $bc$ to entry $32$. The end result is the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Check that...confirm that $v^t A v$ really does give you $a^2 + bc + cb + d^2$.

What about the $n \times n$ case? Well,

1. if the $j$th entry of $v$ corresponds to a diagonal entry of $M$ (like $j = 1, 4$ for $a$ and $d$ in the $2 \times 2$ case), you get a $1$ in the matrix $A$ at location $jj$, i.e., $a_{jj} = 1$. Those entries as $j = 1, n+2, 2n+3, \ldots, n^2$.  And
2. for every other entry of $M$, you'll get a diagonal pair of $1$s like those corresponding to $b$ and $c$. Entry $(ij)$ of $M$ corresponds to coordinate $n(i-1) + j$ of $v$, so for each $i$ and $j$ from $1$ to $n$ where $i \ne j$, we have a $1$ in matrix $a$ at locations $a_{pq}$ and $a_{qp}$, where $p = n(i-1) + j$ and $q = n(j-1) + i$.