# quadratic form from nxn matrices to reals ( Tr(A^2) ). I need to find it's signature and rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, trace, matrix-rank

Firstly prove $Tr(A^2)$ defines a quadratic form from the space of $n \times n$ matrices to R. I think you just have to show that $Tr(A B)$ is a bilinear form which seems too easy to be correct or I'm doing that wrong.

Next I am asked to find the rank and signature of this quadratic form. This doesn't seem to make any sense as I can't see how to decompose it down into $P^T A P$. I've tried writing out the trace a summation but that doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2009_October_17 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639436/find-the-symmetric-matrix-that-represents-the-quadratic-form-qx-tracex2.

Comment: You are correct in your approach to the first part.

Comment: Notice that $tr(AB^t)$ is a inner product in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. What is the sign of $tr(A^2)$ if A is symmetric or skew-symmetric ?